# What's the meaning of "bundle of sticks up your butt" in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

It's from Gilmore Girls, and Lane has to go to a teenage hay ride though she thinks it's silly.
Rory says,

> "I'm still fuzzy on what's fun about sitting in the cold for two hours - *with a bundle of sticks up your butt.*"

I'm not sure about the meaning of the last past of it especially because Urban dictionary says "stick up their butt" describes someone who's unpleasant. 
So is she talking about people who go on a hayride? or stick here means hay?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the context, it sounds like it's possibly a pun, or at least exaggeration.

Loosely speaking, you could call a bale of hay a bundle of sticks. On the one hand, if you're riding a bundle of sticks, well the sticks are uncomfortably close to your butt. You could exaggerate and say they're up your butt. <strike>On the other hand, "bundles of sticks" intensifies the expression. In other words, Lane is being **very** rigid and upright--no fun at all.</strike>

Upon rereading the quote and reconsidering the context, it sounds more like Rory is exaggerating in order to complain about the ride. You don't you usually call a bale of hay a bundle of sticks. But you could call it that in order to emphasize or exaggerate the discomfort. In other words, you could rephrase it as something like

> I don't understand what's fun about sitting in the cold for two hours--on all this uncomfortable hay.

Comment: Thanks, so you mean it could be interpreted in either way? So maybe it's intentional? 1. literally "hay sticks" are attached to her butt since she's gonna be sitting on it 2. being rigid.

Comment: It's intentional if it was meant to be a pun. But after rereading it, it sounds like Rory was complaining that the ride is no fun. Did it look like Rory was complaining about the ride, or complaining about Lane?

Comment: Oh (it seemed like) Rory was definitely making fun about the ride, not Lane. She's not complaining about Lane and Lane herself thinks the hay ride is pointless and she's going there only because her mother forced her to.

Comment: Ok, yeah, that makes sense. I will edit my answer.